# Producing Rolling Averages Within A Data Set

Tags: r, time-series

I have a large data set with multiple subjects. I am trying to create a new column of rolling 5 day rolling averages for some of the variables in the data set. I have been trying to use the zoo and dplyr packages but I can't seem to get it to come out right. I am trying to figure out how to place the NAs in the empty spaces for the first 5 rows.

The data looks something like this:

```html
set.seed(362)
Day <- rep(seq(1:35), times = 3)
variable.1 <- round(rnorm(n = Day, mean = 1200, sd = 300),0)
variable.2 <- round(rnorm(n = Day, mean = 100, sd = 20), 0)
variable.3 <- round(rnorm(n = Day, mean = 20, sd = 5), 1)
data <- data.frame(Day, variable.1, variable.2, variable.3)
Bob <- sample("Bob", 35, replace = T)
Jeff <- sample("Jeff", 35, replace = T)
Kevin <- sample("Kevin", 35, replace = T)
Names <- array(c(Bob, Jeff, Kevin), dim = c(105,1))
data <- cbind(Names, data)
data
```

```html
     Name  Day  variable.2   variable.2  variable.3
1     Bob   1       1369         91       20.6
2     Bob   2       1155         96       18.8
3     Bob   3        999         97       22.4
4     Bob   4        947         93       11.4
5     Bob   5       1442         90       20.1
6     Bob   6       1170        125       17.8
7     Bob   7       1028         81       16.0
8     Bob   8        893        115       30.6
9     Bob   9       1413         76       18.2
10    Bob  10       1510        126       18.8
11    Bob  11       1145        117       19.7
12    Bob  12       1893         83       11.0
13    Bob  13       1559        122       21.9
14    Bob  14       1396         91       27.4
15    Bob  15       1066        105       29.2
16    Bob  16       1319         31       31.4
17    Bob  17        959        134       25.0
18    Bob  18       1325        108       11.8
19    Bob  19       1278         93       17.0
20    Bob  20        909         70       16.2
21    Bob  21        777         84       23.3
22    Bob  22       1770        105       11.6
23    Bob  23       1080         79       14.6
24    Bob  24        855         70       18.7
25    Bob  25       1192         84       15.1
26    Bob  26       1077        116       18.6
27    Bob  27       1376        120       19.6
28    Bob  28       1290        107       20.8
29    Bob  29       1150         96       16.4
30    Bob  30        991        111       22.0
31    Bob  31       1433        113       16.0
32    Bob  32       1125        104       17.8
33    Bob  33       1076        122       21.6
34    Bob  34       1491        113       24.1
35    Bob  35       1163        102       20.0
36   Jeff   1       1151         75       19.4
37   Jeff   2       1375         87       24.7
38   Jeff   3       1508        106       19.1
39   Jeff   4       1569         84       15.4
40   Jeff   5       1279         88       13.5
41   Jeff   6        664        116       21.1
42   Jeff   7        987         69       24.7
43   Jeff   8       1913        121       20.6
44   Jeff   9       1320         99       17.4
45   Jeff  10       1384        126       25.6
46   Jeff  11       1067        118       22.6
47   Jeff  12       1060         81       20.9
48   Jeff  13       1732         97       19.5
49   Jeff  14       1097        112       17.1
50   Jeff  15       1521        105       13.4
51   Jeff  16       1139        123       19.0
52   Jeff  17        996         99       20.8
53   Jeff  18        713        127       27.0
54   Jeff  19       1586         91       15.4
55   Jeff  20        777        119       17.7
56   Jeff  21       1232        106       22.4
57   Jeff  22       1415        116       25.9
58   Jeff  23       1256        117       23.1
59   Jeff  24        955         97       24.3
60   Jeff  25       1503        105       21.1
61   Jeff  26       1965         80       17.6
62   Jeff  27       1281        112       29.7
63   Jeff  28       1467        122       23.8
64   Jeff  29        939        118       17.4
65   Jeff  30       1288         91       20.9
66   Jeff  31       1441         99       16.6
67   Jeff  32       1310         75       23.2
68   Jeff  33       1155        112       22.9
69   Jeff  34       1357         94       29.0
70   Jeff  35       1378         81       26.6
71  Kevin   1       1185         70       16.8
72  Kevin   2       1709        115       24.2
73  Kevin   3       1050        111       10.5
74  Kevin   4       1474        104       10.7
75  Kevin   5       1016         75       20.4
76  Kevin   6        630         98       18.6
77  Kevin   7        949         53       16.4
78  Kevin   8       1284        118       16.6
79  Kevin   9       1255         87        7.7
80  Kevin  10        406        105       14.1
81  Kevin  11       1182        110       16.8
82  Kevin  12        803         73       27.7
83  Kevin  13        960         84       20.3
84  Kevin  14       1192         91       20.6
85  Kevin  15        749        104       22.2
86  Kevin  16        848        106       17.2
87  Kevin  17       1567         77       12.4
88  Kevin  18       1026        127       19.3
89  Kevin  19       1384         93       19.4
90  Kevin  20       1024         96       17.1
91  Kevin  21       1226        105       12.6
92  Kevin  22       1629        110       10.1
93  Kevin  23       1197         64       24.1
94  Kevin  24       1286         82       17.0
95  Kevin  25       1104        103       26.2
96  Kevin  26       1056        108       25.1
97  Kevin  27       1481        145       10.7
98  Kevin  28        949        124       18.8
99  Kevin  29       1230        152       13.5
100 Kevin  30       1481         78       15.4
101 Kevin  31       1437         83       25.0
102 Kevin  32       1446         81       21.3
103 Kevin  33       1501        101       20.0
104 Kevin  34       1288        103       17.8
105 Kevin  35       1338        109       25.0
```

When I have used rollapply and rollmean and indicated the number of days I want rolling, 5, and fill = NA, it seems to always add an NA at the top few rows and an NA in the bottom few rows. However, the NA in the top few rows is always a few short (IE, it begins the putting the 5 day rolling average on Day 3), which makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution if you use the `RcppRoll` package designed to do these things efficiently.

```
library(RcppRoll)
data$v1roll <- c(rep(NA, 4), roll_mean(data$variable.1, 5))
```

or

```
data$v1roll <- roll_mean(data$variable.1, 5, fill=NA, align="right")
```

Comment: This was helpful. I see how the basic structure of the code works and was not familiar with the RcppRoll package before. I used ddply from the plyr package to apply the code to each individual and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`rollapply` and `rollmean` produce centred means by default so with `width = 5` and `fill = NA` one would expect 2 NAs at the beginning and at the end since there is no sequence of 5 components with a middle value at the first, second, second last or last position.

Depending on what you want you could use `align = "right"` or `rollapplyr` to get right alignment or `align = "left"` to get left alignment.    With right alignment, for example, and `fill = NA` all the NAs would appear at the beginning since there is no sequence of 5 that ends at the first, second, third or forth position.

Also depending on what you want try the `partial = TRUE` argument to `rollapply` to get means using partial data at the beginning and/or end.

This is explained on the help page `?rollapply` and the various vignettes that come with zoo and there are examples there too.

Here are some examples of some variations with your data:

```
# center alignment, no fill
rollmean(data$variable.1[1:10], 5)
## [1] 1182.4 1142.6 1117.2 1096.0 1189.2 1202.8

# center alignment, fill
rollmean(data$variable.1[1:10], 5, fill = NA)
## [1]     NA     NA 1182.4 1142.6 1117.2 1096.0 1189.2 1202.8     NA     NA

# right alignment, fill
rollmeanr(data$variable.1[1:10], 5, fill = NA)
## [1]     NA     NA     NA     NA 1182.4 1142.6 1117.2 1096.0 1189.2 1202.8

# left alignment, fill
rollmean(data$variable.1[1:10], 5, fill = NA, align = "left")
## [1] 1182.4 1142.6 1117.2 1096.0 1189.2 1202.8     NA     NA     NA     NA

# right alignment, partial
rollapplyr(data$variable.1[1:10], 5, mean, partial = TRUE)
## [1] 1369.000 1262.000 1174.333 1117.500 1182.400 1142.600 1117.200 1096.000
## [9] 1189.200 1202.800
```